# How can I refer to a relative subdomain in HTML?

Tags: html, hyperlink, subdomain

Let's say I have a website which is accessed by multiple domains, e.g. `domain1.com` and `domain2.com`.

If I have a relative link, such as `href="/wiki"`, then no matter what domain name I access the website by, that link will take me to the correct place.

Lets say instead I wanted to use `wiki.domain1.com` and `wiki.domain2.com`, is there some way I can make a link to this relative to the domain name?

If not, is there an elegant way to handle a link such as the wiki link above when multiple domains point to the same server?

Comment: FYI any link starting with a forward slash is absolute, not relative.

Comment: Using javascript you can easily change client-side all links in order to insert "wiki." if they send to "http://domain*.com/wiki".

Comment: @Christian Links starting with a forward slash `/` are called root-relative links. [source](https://www.internetingishard.com/html-and-css/links-and-images/)

Answer (score 15):

No. You'll have to give the whole domain. To link from `domain1.com` to `wiki.domain1.com`, the link has to look like `href="http://wiki.domain1.com"`.

Comment: Thanks, is there an elegant way to handle this when multiple domain names refer to the same server? (Adding this to question).

Comment: You can usually figure out the current domain name using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. Write your script around that...

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible with relative paths, because subdomain is in fact a whole different domain.

If you really can't use absolute URL, but can use PHP, you could try this proxy script:

```
<?php

if(!isset($_GET['url'])) {
    die('Missing URL!');
}

$subdomain_url = 'http://subdomain.example.com/';
$file_path = $_GET['url'];

$file_url = $subdomain_url . $file_path;

$mime = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME, $file_url);


header('Content-Type: ' . $mime);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary'); 
header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="' . basename($file_path) . '"'); 

readfile($file_url);
```

Save it into a file, eg. *imgproxy.php*, and then you can link images on the other subdomain like this:

```
<img src="imgproxy.php?url=images/logo.png">
```