# How to use relative path to load css in subdomain?

Tags: html, css

I have a html file at `www.mydomain.com/index.html`

this index use a css file `main.css`

```
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

I use relative path to load the css file, but I got error `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`, because it get the css file form `mydomain.com/css/main.css`

Why cannot use same URL to load css file?

Comment: Where is the actual CSS file located?

Comment: do you have tag `<base ... />` somewhere in you document?

Comment: actual CSS file located in www.mydomain.com/css/main.css, I just try base tag, it still get css from `mydomain.com` not `www.mydomain.com`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793088/how-can-i-refer-to-a-relative-subdomain-in-html

Comment: @Siguza , I just use one domain for the website, `mydomain.com` is not for this website, and this is html website, no php can be used.

Comment: Could you please give us a link to your website? This is a very strange behavior.

Comment: I just found the problem, this is the link, `www.addpost.hk/test/AddPost/src/main/webapp/` , only the folder `resources` has this problem, if you go to other folder, it is no problem. I still cannot found the reason, I have deleted every .htaccess file.