# href to subdomain redirects to folder instead of subdomain

Tags: html, subdomain, href

My domain is mydomain.com and there is a href to my subdomain test:

```
<a href="http://test.mydomain.com/">test</a>
```

The href redirects to **`mydomain.com/test./`** instead of **`test.mydomain.com`**. I have included the `http://` in the `href`, so it shouldn't refer to the original page. If I right click the link and select 'open in new tab' it works perfectly. If I add an `target="_blank"`, which should do the same thing, I end up with the same error as described above.

Edit: on mobile it works fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I refer to a relative subdomain in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793088/how-can-i-refer-to-a-relative-subdomain-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

Your subdomain is not properly created. check you Subdomain in Cpanel. Also create namespace for you domain in your hosting server portal.